unable to show the log in stream log
I'm trying the Azure AI search. the backend using python and run as linux web app. in parts of app/backend/approaches/charreadretrieveread.py
async def run_until_final_call(
        self,
        history: list[dict[str, str]],
        overrides: dict[str, Any],
        auth_claims: dict[str, Any],
        should_stream: bool = False,
    ) -> tuple[dict[str, Any], Coroutine[Any, Any, Union[ChatCompletion, AsyncStream[ChatCompletionChunk]]]]:
        #print("/chat user question: " , history[-1])
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        logging.info('Hello, logging!')

Although no error raised in this moment, but In Azure protal, the 'Hello, logging!' is not showing at the backend -> streaming log.
in backend -> web service log, I have set
level: verbose
application logging: file system
quota: 35 mb
retention periods(days): 1


I tried a sample code to print logs in the Log Stream of Azure web apps.
Code :
from flask import Flask
import logging
from typing import Any, Coroutine, Union

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ChatCompletion:
    pass

class AsyncStream:
    pass

class ChatCompletionChunk:
    pass

search_service_endpoint = "https://<search_name>.search.windows.net"
index_name = "<index_name>"
api_key = "<search_apiKey>"

async def run_until_final_call(
    history: list[dict[str, str]],
    overrides: dict[str, Any],
    auth_claims: dict[str, Any],
    should_stream: bool = False,
) -> tuple[dict[str, Any], Coroutine[Any, Any, Union[ChatCompletion, AsyncStream, ChatCompletionChunk]]]:
    pass

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    logger.info('Hello, logging!')
    return 'Hello, Kamali!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)

Local Output :
The code ran successfully, as shown below.

Azure Portal :
After deployment, I enabled the File System in App Service logs for the Azure web apps, as displayed below.

I was then able to see the logs in the Azure web app Log Streams.


@aaa aaa Did you get a chance to look into the solution I provided?
